Undefined variable when returning view from controller in Laravel
I have a Laravel controller method designed to truncate strings from a Profile model and pass them to a view. However, I'm encountering an "Undefined variable $cutJobTitle" error when trying to display the truncated strings in the Blade template.
Here is my controller method:
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\Profiles;


use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Profile;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function cutStr(Profile $profil)
    {
        $cutJobTitle = Str::words($profil->job_title, 30, '...');
        $cutSociety = Str::words($profil->society, 30, '...');

        return view('pages.dashboard.profile.index', compact('profil', 'cutJobTitle', 'cutSociety'));
    }
}

And here is the relevant part of my Blade template (profile/index.blade.php):
<span>{{ $cutJobTitle }} - {{ $cutSociety }}</span>

When I load the page, I get the following error: Undefined variable $cutJobTitle
I Tried:

Route Definition: I tried adding a route to my web.php to explicitly call the cutStr method, thinking it might be a routing issue:

Route::get('/profile/{id}', [ProfileController::class, 'cutStr']);


Direct Assignment: I tried assigning the truncated strings directly in the view, but it seems the variables are not being passed correctly from the controller.

Checked Variable Names: I double-checked that the variable names in the compact method match those used in the Blade template.


I expected the cutJobTitle and cutSociety variables to be available in my blade.php so that I could display the truncated job title and society name.

Is this the view loading directly or are you including it within the view?

Replace the $cutJobTitle = Str... code line in your Controller, with some sample data like $cutJobTitle = "Hello World"; and see if the problem still exists. if the sample string printed in the view, so there is problem with retrieving data from your Profile model.

Please pass the array in the compact like compact(['profile', 'cutJobTitle', 'cutSociety']).

@HarshilPatanvadiya What is the difference?

include in your question the output of php artisan route:list --path=profile/{id}

You are sending {id} in your route and on the controller side there is an Object. That's the wrong way. The correct way to do is:
public function cutStr($id)
{
    $profil=Profile::find($id);
    $cutJobTitle = Str::words($profil->job_title, 30, '...');
    $cutSociety = Str::words($profil->society, 30, '...');

    return view('pages.dashboard.profile.index', compact('profil', 
    'cutJobTitle', 'cutSociety'));
}

